# Google Map Marker Using PlaceID Android

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

How can I create a location marker using a place_id instead of longitude and latitude coordinates?

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    //I want to use the place_id to place in of the Latitude and Longitude 
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title(" Sydney"));    
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that is supported in the Maps API.

Instead, you would need to implement a reverse lookup for a given PlaceID to return the Lat Long and pass that into the addMarker function.

If you are using the Places API to get the Place ID in the first place, querying the Place Details will give richer information about location - https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details

Comment: Thanks I had opted for that. Though i thought it can be done rather than the reverse look up.

Comment: If you have the PlaceId from a LatLong query, ignore step 1 - but you can only get the Place Details info from a call with a valid PlaceId (AFAIK)